# Try to use spring-data-ldap with ActiveDirectory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, spring-data, spring-ldap

I try to use Spring-Data-Ldap with an ActiveDirectory.
I want to list users and find a specific user.

My main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableLdapRepositories
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The UserRepo :

```
public interface UserRepo extends LdapRepository<User> {
    List<User> findByFullNameContains(String name);
}
```

Part of application.yml

```
spring:
    ldap:
        urls: ldap://fr-dc1.groupefdi.priv:389
        base: DC=groupefdi,DC=priv
        username: CN=user,CN=Users,DC=groupefdi,DC=priv
        password: ******
```

I get the error:

```
2017-09-06 14:42:34,551 [ERROR]  --- [http-nio-6546-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]:181 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); nested exception is javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name '/'] with root cause
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2914) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2888) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1846) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:276) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$3.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:303) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1840) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.findAll(LdapTemplate.java:1806) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.findAll(LdapTemplate.java:1814) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.support.SimpleLdapRepository.findAll(SimpleLdapRepository.java:190) ~[spring-data-ldap-1.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
  .....
```

I don't know if I have to put something special on the application.yml for Active Directory or if I make a mistake some where.

Answer (score 4):

Before sending request try to add:

`ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);`

**Update:**

If you use ldap repositories you can set this flag during configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories
class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    ContextSource contextSource() {

        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        ldapContextSource.setUrl("ldap://127.0.0.1:389");

        return ldapContextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(ContextSource contextSource) {
        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
        return ldapTemplate;
    }
}
```

In this case you will ignore patial result exception for each ldap request.

Comment: Thanks. It remove the exception. But the result was empty when I try userRepo.findAll()

Comment: @BokC, username: CN=user,CN=Users,DC=groupefdi,DC=priv. Why did you define CN twice?

Comment: The first one is the login

Comment: @BokC, Please double check user DN. May be you miss user roles or something else.

Comment: I think userDn is ok. Ma application make a connection with the Active Directory server. But I think the query made by Spring-data-ldap is not good. Perhaps I have to change the method called.

Comment: while using ldapRepository how to set above boolean value.